# can't connect to wireless printer

Tags: macos, network, wifi, printing

I have an Epson Workforce 845 printer. I have it setup on my wireless network correctly. I can print to it without any trouble from a couple different windows computers but I only have intermittent success on my mac. Usually when I go to print in the print queue it will say "Looking for printer." then "The printer is not connected."

I have tried resetting the print system, reinstalling drivers from apple and epson. nothing works.

My printer is on a static ip 192.168.0.65. The network settings confirmation sheet printed by the printer confirms this. If I ping that address from my mac sometimes it is successful and sometimes it gives the error `ping: sendto: Host is down` `Request timeout for icmp_seq 0`. I'm no pro at the command line but I tried nmap -A 192.168.0.1/24 and this is the relevant section

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.65
Host is up (0.031s latency).
Not shown: 994 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE     VERSION
80/tcp   open  http?
|_http-methods: No Allow or Public header in OPTIONS response (status code 405)
|_http-title: Site doesn't have a title (text/html).
139/tcp  open  tcpwrapped
445/tcp  open  netbios-ssn
515/tcp  open  printer
631/tcp  open  ipp?
|_http-methods: No Allow or Public header in OPTIONS response (status code 405)
|_http-title: Site doesn't have a title (text/html).
9100/tcp open  jetdirect?
2 services unrecognized despite returning data. If you know the service/version, please submit the following fingerprints at http://www.insecure.org/cgi-bin/servicefp-submit.cgi :
==============NEXT SERVICE FINGERPRINT (SUBMIT INDIVIDUALLY)==============
SF-Port80-TCP:V=6.25%I=7%D=7/29%Time=51F686A2%P=x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0%
SF:r(GetRequest,34A,"HTTP/1\.1\x20200\x20OK\r\nCONTENT-TYPE:\x20text/html\
SF:r\nCONTENT-LENGTH:\x20728\r\nSERVER:\x20EPSON_Linux\x20UPnP/1\.0\x20Eps
SF:on\x20UPnP\x20SDK/1\.0\r\n\r\n<!DOCTYPE\x20HTML\x20PUBLIC\x20\"-//W3C//
SF:DTD\x20HTML\x204\.01//EN\x20\"\r\n\"http://www\.w3\.org/TR/html4/strict
SF:\.dtd\">\r\n<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<meta\x20http-equiv=\"Content-Type\"\x2
SF:0content=\"text/html;\x20charset=utf-8\">\r\n<meta\x20name=\"Author\"\x
SF:20content=\"SEIKO\x20EPSON\">\r\n<meta\x20name=\"format-detection\"\x20
SF:content=\"telephone=no\">\r\n<script\x20type=\"text/javascript\">\r\nva
SF:r\x20path\x20=\x20location\.href;\r\nvar\x20Ret;\r\nRet\x20=\x20path\.i
SF:ndexOf\(\"/PRESENTATION/HTML/TOP/INDEX\.HTML\",\x200\);\r\nif\x20\(-1\x
SF:20<\x20Ret\)\x20{\r\n}\x20else\x20{\r\nRet\x20=\x20path\.indexOf\(\"PRE
SF:SENTATION\",0\);\r\nif\x20\(-1\x20<\x20Ret\)\x20{\r\ndocument\.write\(\
SF:"<meta\x20http-equiv\x20=\x20'refresh'\x20content='0;\x20URL=\x20\./HTM
SF:L/TOP/INDEX\.HTML'>\"\);\r\n}\x20else\x20{\r\ndocument\.write\(\"<meta\
SF:x20http-equiv\x20=\x20'refresh'\x20content='0;\x20URL=\x20\./PRESENTATI
SF:ON/HTML/TOP/INDEX\.HTML'>\"\);\r\n}\r\n}\r\n</script>\r\n</head>\r\n</H
SF:TML>")%r(HTTPOptions,67,"HTTP/1\.1\x20405\x20Method\x20Not\x20Allowed\r
SF:\nCONTENT-LENGTH:\x200\r\nSERVER:\x20EPSON_Linux\x20UPnP/1\.0\x20Epson\
SF:x20UPnP\x20SDK/1\.0\r\n\r\n")%r(RTSPRequest,7A,"HTTP/1\.1\x20405\x20Met
SF:hod\x20Not\x20Allowed\r\nCONTENT-LENGTH:\x200\r\nSERVER:\x20EPSON_Linux
SF:\x20UPnP/1\.0\x20Epson\x20UPnP\x20SDK/1\.0\r\nCONNECTION:\x20close\r\n\
SF:r\n")%r(FourOhFourRequest,6A,"HTTP/1\.1\x20500\x20Internal\x20Server\x2
SF:0Error\r\nCONTENT-LENGTH:\x200\r\nSERVER:\x20EPSON_Linux\x20UPnP/1\.0\x
SF:20Epson\x20UPnP\x20SDK/1\.0\r\n\r\n")%r(GenericLines,39,"HTTP/1\.0\x205
SF:00\x20Internal\x20Server\x20Error\r\nContent-Length:\x200\r\n\r\n")%r(S
SF:IPOptions,7A,"HTTP/1\.1\x20405\x20Method\x20Not\x20Allowed\r\nCONTENT-L
SF:ENGTH:\x200\r\nSERVER:\x20EPSON_Linux\x20UPnP/1\.0\x20Epson\x20UPnP\x20
SF:SDK/1\.0\r\nCONNECTION:\x20close\r\n\r\n");
==============NEXT SERVICE FINGERPRINT (SUBMIT INDIVIDUALLY)==============
SF-Port631-TCP:V=6.25%I=7%D=7/29%Time=51F686A3%P=x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.0
SF:%r(GetRequest,34A,"HTTP/1\.1\x20200\x20OK\r\nCONTENT-TYPE:\x20text/html
SF:\r\nCONTENT-LENGTH:\x20728\r\nSERVER:\x20EPSON_Linux\x20UPnP/1\.0\x20Ep
SF:son\x20UPnP\x20SDK/1\.0\r\n\r\n<!DOCTYPE\x20HTML\x20PUBLIC\x20\"-//W3C/
SF:/DTD\x20HTML\x204\.01//EN\x20\"\r\n\"http://www\.w3\.org/TR/html4/stric
SF:t\.dtd\">\r\n<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<meta\x20http-equiv=\"Content-Type\"\x
SF:20content=\"text/html;\x20charset=utf-8\">\r\n<meta\x20name=\"Author\"\
SF:x20content=\"SEIKO\x20EPSON\">\r\n<meta\x20name=\"format-detection\"\x2
SF:0content=\"telephone=no\">\r\n<script\x20type=\"text/javascript\">\r\nv
SF:ar\x20path\x20=\x20location\.href;\r\nvar\x20Ret;\r\nRet\x20=\x20path\.
SF:indexOf\(\"/PRESENTATION/HTML/TOP/INDEX\.HTML\",\x200\);\r\nif\x20\(-1\
SF:x20<\x20Ret\)\x20{\r\n}\x20else\x20{\r\nRet\x20=\x20path\.indexOf\(\"PR
SF:ESENTATION\",0\);\r\nif\x20\(-1\x20<\x20Ret\)\x20{\r\ndocument\.write\(
SF:\"<meta\x20http-equiv\x20=\x20'refresh'\x20content='0;\x20URL=\x20\./HT
SF:ML/TOP/INDEX\.HTML'>\"\);\r\n}\x20else\x20{\r\ndocument\.write\(\"<meta
SF:\x20http-equiv\x20=\x20'refresh'\x20content='0;\x20URL=\x20\./PRESENTAT
SF:ION/HTML/TOP/INDEX\.HTML'>\"\);\r\n}\r\n}\r\n</script>\r\n</head>\r\n</
SF:HTML>")%r(HTTPOptions,67,"HTTP/1\.1\x20405\x20Method\x20Not\x20Allowed\
SF:r\nCONTENT-LENGTH:\x200\r\nSERVER:\x20EPSON_Linux\x20UPnP/1\.0\x20Epson
SF:\x20UPnP\x20SDK/1\.0\r\n\r\n")%r(GenericLines,39,"HTTP/1\.0\x20500\x20I
SF:nternal\x20Server\x20Error\r\nContent-Length:\x200\r\n\r\n")%r(RTSPRequ
SF:est,7A,"HTTP/1\.1\x20405\x20Method\x20Not\x20Allowed\r\nCONTENT-LENGTH:
SF:\x200\r\nSERVER:\x20EPSON_Linux\x20UPnP/1\.0\x20Epson\x20UPnP\x20SDK/1\
SF:.0\r\nCONNECTION:\x20close\r\n\r\n")%r(FourOhFourRequest,6A,"HTTP/1\.1\
SF:x20500\x20Internal\x20Server\x20Error\r\nCONTENT-LENGTH:\x200\r\nSERVER
SF::\x20EPSON_Linux\x20UPnP/1\.0\x20Epson\x20UPnP\x20SDK/1\.0\r\n\r\n")%r(
SF:SIPOptions,7A,"HTTP/1\.1\x20405\x20Method\x20Not\x20Allowed\r\nCONTENT-
SF:LENGTH:\x200\r\nSERVER:\x20EPSON_Linux\x20UPnP/1\.0\x20Epson\x20UPnP\x2
SF:0SDK/1\.0\r\nCONNECTION:\x20close\r\n\r\n");

Host script results:
|_nbstat: NetBIOS name: EPSONBBD4DC, NetBIOS user: <unknown>, NetBIOS MAC: <unknown>
| smb-os-discovery: 
|   OS: EPSON Storage Server (NQ 4.32)
|   NetBIOS computer name: 
|   Workgroup: 
|_  System time: 2006-12-19T16:43:39+00:00
| smb-security-mode: 
|   Account that was used for smb scripts: guest
|   User-level authentication
|   SMB Security: Challenge/response passwords supported
|_  Message signing disabled (dangerous, but default)
|_smbv2-enabled: Server doesn't support SMBv2 protocol
```

Traceroute results

```
traceroute to 192.168.0.65 (192.168.0.65), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * *traceroute: sendto: No route to host
traceroute: wrote 192.168.0.65 52 chars, ret=-1
 *
traceroute: sendto: Host is down
 3 traceroute: wrote 192.168.0.65 52 chars, ret=-1
 *traceroute: sendto: Host is down
traceroute: wrote 192.168.0.65 52 chars, ret=-1
```

Sometimes randomly I am able to print once or twice from my mac but subsequent print jobs fail. Also after resetting the print system sometimes the printer doesn't show up in the add printer dialog.

EDIT:

When the printer stops working for me and I try to open the Epson Printer Utility it won't open. Even though everyone else can still print and I was able to print when I tried 15 minutes prior. Even though it says it can't find the printer, in System Preferences I can see the printer switch from "Idle" to "In Use" and vice versa.

Can anyone help me out with a fix or a way to diagnose what's wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Does it print over USB ? Also how (as what) does it show up in your wifi scan ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 it prints fine over USB but ideally it needs to be wireless because many computers are using the same printer. What wifi scan are you talking about?

Comment: So far it looks like it is not the printer driver. But was wondering about your network settings, still reading the protocol you published with printer sharing enabled.

Comment: Is there another device on the network that might have that IP-number (either statically given or accidentially handed out with DHCP)?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen no the printer is the only device with that ip address

Comment: I had a similar problen with AirPrint ón an HP printer as configured by the official tool.  I changed the static IP address to be a dynamic one and it worked.

Comment: → Devin: you can remove the `nmap` analysis because it doesn't help to analyze corectly a basic wireless problem. A `ping` is largly enough to show that your Mac doesn't reach your Epson printer.

Comment: → Devin: could you include in your problem analysis all the IP involved, and a screen copy of the wireless network location used by your Mac.

Comment: @danielAzuelos There are many devices on the network I'm not sure which ip addresses you want to know. Workstations are generally in the 192.168.0.200-299 range, ip phones are in the 100-199 range and peripherals are in the 50-99 range. Which wireless network dialog would be helpful for you to see?

Comment: → Devin: all the IP adresses involved == the IP address of the Epson printer, the Mac failing and one of the computer accessing the printer. Of courses, provide the IP addresses on the wireless side.
Since this information may help anyone wanting to help you, please include them in your initial description to replace the nmap output.